# Prevent uibModal to popup if user was not Authenticated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use $uibModal to popup only for Authenticated user. It turned out that the alert fired correctly, but the popup still show up after closing alert.
How to prevent the modal to show up.

```
vm.popupRequestForm = function () {
        var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/common/request/requestModal.view.html',
            controller: 'requestModalCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                coachData: function() {
                    return { 
                       coachid: vm.coachid,
                       shortDescription: vm.data.coach.shortDescription
                    };
                }
            }
        });


        if ($rootScope.isAuthenticated === true) {
             uibModalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
             console.log(data); 
            })
        } else {
            alert('Please log in to continue');
            return false;
        }
};
```

Comment: You aren't showing where you open the modal so presumably, it's not effected by the logic in your question. Also, the `else` is completely redundant as you're `return`-ing in the `if` section

Comment: Um., I'm not clear what I should do. I have edited the question.

Comment: Move your `isAuthenticated` check **before** you call `$uibModal.open()`

Comment: That's cool! Thanks a lot. I thought the function won't call untill the uibModalInstance.result line, so I missed to check auth there.

Comment: You should read the documentation